# WebClient filter to add Authentication header

Tags: spring-boot, http, webclient, spring-webclient

I'm about to implement a number of requests to external services that require an Authentication header.

The authentication service is an external service and in order to retrieve the Token, I need to make an HTTP call.

The strategy i'm thinking of moving forward with is to create append a filter to WebClient that calls this service to get the token and then add it to the header.

Of course I'm going to implement some caching layer to retrieve the token, but the point is that I'm going to add a request to my request.

Do you think it's a valid approach? Or should I just explicitly call the Authentication Service outside of the main request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's OAuth2 and you need the JWT token for your request, Spring Security and the `WebClient` is also capable of doing this ([Spring WebFlux based example](https://rieckpil.de/spring-webclient-oauth2-integration-for-spring-web-servlet/), [Spring Web example](https://rieckpil.de/spring-webclient-oauth2-integration-using-github-as-an-example/)). I wouldn't implement this logic within a filter, rather create a `WebClient` filter to set the `Authorization: Bearer XYZ` header for each request and pass the token from *outside* or by Spring.

You can also have a look at this [library](https://github.com/zalando/tokens). It fetches OAuth2 tokens in a background thread regularly for you and you can pass it to your `WebClient`.

A custom filter for the `WebClient` may look like the following:

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction authHeader(String token) {
    return (request, next) -> next.exchange(ClientRequest.from(request).headers((headers) -> {
      headers.setBearerAuth(token);
    }).build());
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where the "String token " param comes from ? I mean, we have to include this filter to the Webclient.builder().. stage. So here this parameter is not available right?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding a token when creating your `WebClient` with the builder, you can pass a lambda function that delegates to calling your token provider that retrieves the latest token

Answer (score 2):

You can use existing `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction` filter from `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` package.

```
@Bean
  WebClient webClient() {
      ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction bearer = new ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction();
      return WebClient.builder()
              .filter(bearer).build();
  }
```